# When coding in nodejs, should I worry about context-switching?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, concurrency

I know that `node.js` my code runs in a single thread, and it is not concurrent, but should I worry about context-switching as a result of multiple `REST` requests or `setTimeout` triggers?

In other words, despite not being **concurrent**, is `node.js` **async**?

As an example, in the following code:

```
let a = 0;

const inc = () => new Promise(resolve => {
    temp = number;      // 1
    number = temp + 1;  // 2
    resolve();
});
```

If I call `inc` 10 times, am I guranteed to end up with 10, or can I have a context switch between the lines marked 1 and 2?

Answer (score 2):

You can write asynchronous code in NodeJS.

You'll get indeterminate results if you have code like this:

```js
let a = 0;

new Promise((resolve, reject) => { /* do something */}).then(() => { a = 1; }).then(() => { /* more stuff */});
new Promise((resolve, reject) => { /* do something */}).then(() => { a = 2; }).then(() => { /* more stuff */});
```

Both promises will act on the global variable `a`, and because there is no way to determine which one will finish first, there is no way to know what the value of `a` will be going forward in either of the promises.

One last thing - because your question uses the word "worry", it leads me to believe that it's something that'd be on your mind. If that's the case, there are several patterns, like the [Reader pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_%28functional_programming%29%23Environment_monad) in functional programming or [Dependency Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection), that help mitigate worrying about race conditions. Those are good practices in any language (NodeJS included), so it may be helpful to read up on them.

Comment: can context switch also in the middle of a promise? If instead of a=1 you had temp = a; a = temp+1;

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "in the middle of a promise", but in the example you give, temp would take the value of a and not a reference to the value of a. so if a changes subsequently, temp will not.

Comment: I added a clarifying example to the question